# Implement double sqrt(double x) in C++

Tags: c++, sqrt

Implement `double sqrt(double x)` in C++ without using std library.

This is a facebook interview question I saw here. http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Implement-double-sqrt-double-x-in-C-QTN_87210.htm
Any other good idea about this?...

!!!Edited.!!!(without using std library.)

Comment: `#include <cmath>` [newline] `double sqrt(double x) { return std::sqrt(x); }`

Comment: @James: I was thinking `#include <cmath>` [newline] `double sqrt(double x)  { return std::pow(x, 0.5); }`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Comment: This must be one of the silliest interview questions. Do they want someone capable of C++ or someone knowing algorithms, which can easily be looked up?

Comment: This is not a 'programming' question, this is a maths theory question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Sqrt_Prec_VS_Speed.aspx). This CodeProject article compares 14 different methods for computing the square root.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one of the most genius sqrt implementations which can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root). It is not the most accurate, but extremely fast.

```
float fast_sqrt(float number) {
   long i;
   float x2, y;
   const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

   x2 = number * 0.5F;
   y  = number;
   i  = * ( long * ) &y;                     // floating point bit level hacking [sic]
   i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );             // Newton's approximation
   y  = * ( float * ) &i;
   y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) ); // 1st iteration
   y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) ); // 2nd iteration
   y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) ); // 3rd iteration

   return 1/y;
}
```

Comment: And you mean to tell us that's what you think the answer should have been at interview?

Comment: Did he want the job? You are supposed to try and impress them during the interview.

Comment: @Tony: "I'd use the methodology of the fast inverse square root function from Quake - that formula is amazing - do you know if it?" would probably suffice.  (though technically, this does 3 passes of newton-raphson approximation instead of 1... so it's not quite the same thing)

Comment: oh ya, I added those for a bit more accuracy, and forgot to take them out. basically the same thing tho.

Comment: @regality: I've used this approach on integers and for 32bits a single iteration was sufficient for 100% accuracy (picked random numbers and including edges), have you checked the extra iterations for `float` ?

Comment: @James, @regality: spit it out from memory &  it may well impress.  But, what are they likely to expect?  If it's not a job where you're that level of maths can be expected, or sqrt is particularly relevant, then just a working implementation of a practical, common-sense approach such as successive approximation.  The fact that it's a constant power of 0.5 and not a log or other function is probably incidental.  A reference to Quake would rate as a curiosity to me if you couldn't explain the algo, just as "C++ boost::any gives run-time typing" isn't worth much sans implementation insight.

Comment: OK I hope your okay with BoneOS using this..  We have cited its originality. Source https://github.com/Bone-Project/BoneOS/blob/amanuel_progress_kbd/libc/math/sqrtk/sqrtk.c

Answer (score 4):

The two obvious answers are bisection (semi-slow) and Newton-Raphson/Leibniz iteration (usually faster). To keep from spoiling anybody's fun, I'll do a reinterpret_cast on the question -- here's an implementation of an integer square root in 8086 assembly language using the Newton-Raphson technique:

```
isqrt proc uses di, number:word
;
; uses bx, cx, dx
;
    mov di,number
    mov ax,255
start_loop:
    mov bx,ax
    xor dx,dx
    mov ax,di
    div bx
    add ax,bx
    shr ax,1
    mov cx,ax
    sub cx,bx
    cmp cx,2
    ja  start_loop
    ret
isqrt endp
```

This is open to some improvement -- it uses x/2 as its initial guess at the sqrt(x). With 386+ instructions, you can use `bsr` to find the most significant bit that's set to get a rough approximation of log<sub>2</sub>x, and divide that by 2 to get your initial approximation.

OTOH, this really only made sense on ancient processors. For anything since the 486 (or so) that has built-in floating point hardware, it's nearly certain that the `FSQRT` instruction will beat this (or pretty much anything else you can write).

Comment: as far as I know using the Reciprocal approach http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Reciprocal_of_the_square_root is faster, probably because it substitutes clever hacks to looping. I am unsure of its precision though.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Yes, if you change the problem, you can improve speed a bit. Most of them also do a *very* crude approximation that only good for around 10 or 12 bits (which is still ~1 pixel at typical resolutions). For an actual square root, however, it's *really* hard to beat dedicated hardware.

Comment: yes obviously, but I was referring to assembly function you wrote :) I've used the Reciprocal approach with perfect precision on integers, and I guess that adding some Newton's iterations would improve the precision somewhat. What's interesting is getting a good first approximation anyway, you can then refine the precision depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I am allowed to use log (ln) and exp then of course exp(log(x)/2) will give me the square root.

Assuming not:

If our value we find the sqrt of is x and the start value is y then we iterate y->(y+x/y)/2

Terminating condition would either be a proximity of y to its previous value or of y*y to x.

With 385 as my x value I get these values in my iterations (Excel)

```
1
193
97.49740933
50.7231161
29.15667189
21.1805984
19.67880541
19.62150055
19.62141687
19.62141687
```

You can use an "approximate" 2^(log base 2(x)/2) as a start point instead of 1. 
385 has a log somewhere between 8 and 9, so if we say 8.5 and therefore start with 2^4.25. If we do this linear between 16 and 32 then we would start with 20.

Starting with 20 I get there in just 4 steps:

```
20
19.625
19.6214172
19.62141687
```

but it required previous "iterations" to calculate the approximate log and exponential.