# How to get this sqrt inline assembly working for iOS

Tags: ios, assembly, inline-assembly

I am trying to follow [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000109/implement-double-sqrtdouble-x-in-c) and implement [sqrt14](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69941/Best-Square-Root-Method-Algorithm-Function-Precisi) within my iOS app:

```
double inline __declspec (naked) __fastcall sqrt14(double n)
{
    _asm fld qword ptr [esp+4]
    _asm fsqrt
    _asm ret 8
}
```

I have modified this to the following in my code:

```
double inline __declspec (naked) sqrt14(double n)
{
    __asm__("fld qword ptr [esp+4]");
    __asm__("fsqrt");
    __asm__("ret 8");
}
```

Above, I have removed the "__fastcall" keyword from the method definition since my understanding is that it is for x86 only. The above gives the following errors for each assembly line respectively:

Unexpected token in argument list

Invalid instruction

Invalid instruction

I have attempted to read through a few [inline ASM guides](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline-asm) and [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238010/how-do-i-do-inline-assembly-on-the-iphone) on how to do this, but I am generally just unfamiliar with the language. I know MIPS quite well, but these commands/registers seem to be very different. For example, I don't understand why the original author never uses the passed in "n" value anywhere in the assembly code.

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated! I am trying to do this because I am building an app where I need to calculate sqrt (ok, yes, I could do a lookup table, but for right now I care a lot about precision) on every pixel of a live-video feed. I am currently using the standard sqrt, and in addition to the rest of the computation, I'm running at around 8fps. Hoping to bump that up a frame or two with this change.

If it matters: I'm building the app to ideally be compatibly with any current iOS device that can run iOS 7.1 Again, many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is perfectly capable of generating `fsqrt` instruction, you don't need inline asm for that. You might get some extra speed if you use `-ffast-math`.

For completeness' sake, here is the inline asm version:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("fsqrt" : "=t" (n) : "0" (n));
```

The `fsqrt` instruction has no explicit operands, it uses the top of the stack implicitly. The `=t` constraint tells the compiler to expect the output on the top of the fpu stack and the `0` constraint instructs the compiler to place the input in the same place as output `#0` (ie. the top of the fpu stack again).

Note that `fsqrt` is of course x86-only, meaning it wont work for example on ARM cpus.

Comment: Oh, so if it's x86-only then it won't work at all on iOS, correct? Also, when you say -ffast-math, do you mean as a compiler flag?

Comment: Yes it only works on x86. And yes, `-ffast-math` is a compiler flag, it turns off error checking, among other things. The flag does work on other architectures too.

Comment: Great, thanks! That flag did help speed up the program! When I put the code above into Xcode it gives the error: "Invalid output constraint '=t' in asm"